# Storing and accessing folder from cloud in android

Tags: android, cloud-storage

I am developing an app that would upload files to a folder in cloud. I have searched a lot but could not find a storage in which I can store my files directly. For example, if I have a file in mnt/sdcard/upoad/ folder in my android device, how to create the same folder in a cloud server programmatically? Is this possible in the first place? Any response would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [DropBox API?](https://www.dropbox.com/developers).

Comment: I have added the DropboxAPI to eclipse and cleaned and rebuild the project. However, I am getting the following error : 11-08 14:32:24.952: W/dalvikvm(9280): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3310: Lcom/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI;.putFileOverwrite (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/io/InputStream;JLcom/dropbox/client2/ProgressListener;)Lcom/dropbox/client2/DropboxAPI$Entry;

Comment: I am using eclipse revision 22 and have included the Android Private Libraries in the "Order and Export" tab of "Java Build Path"

Comment: It's probably an API level issue.  You may need to upgrade your Eclipse support.

Comment: Dropnox API works perfect for uploading files. I was able to upload all the files from my phone onto Dropbox. Now how do I restore them back all at once? I have tried using api.metadata but does not seem to work. Basically, my app is storing the info in DropBox and will retrieve it back when required.